# How can I assign a role to a new member?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Here is my code:

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  const channel = member.guild.channels.find(ch => ch.name === 'welcome');
  if (!channel) return;

  channel.send(message.author.toString() + ', Welcome!');

  member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Guest"));
});
```

I'm trying to make it so that new members are assigned a "Guest" role but that isn't working.
Here is the error message:

```
(node:677408) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
<@321191321437995009>, Please repeat these numbers to me to verify that you are a human: 421792
(node:677408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Missing Permissions
    at item.request.gen.end (C:\Users\PlusTwenty\Documents\Bots\Welcome\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\rest\RequestHandlers\Sequential.js:79:15)
    at then (C:\Users\PlusTwenty\Documents\Bots\Welcome\node_modules\snekfetch\src\index.js:215:21)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:677408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
```

Comment: "but that isn't working." Do you get an error message? I always get very clear errors when something goes wrong. Maybe the bot does not have permissions to the roles?

Comment: Why don't you look at the message? `Missing Permissions` - or can you share the bot permissions?

Comment: @KoenHollander the bot is an administrator

Comment: Check that the bot's role is above the "Guest" role you're trying to add

Answer (score 0):

Here's where you went wrong.

```
member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name", "Guest"));
```

Instead, you need to define the role before you actually call the add role function. (Not really, but its recommended)

```
var role = member.guild.roles.find("name", "Guild");
```

(If you dont, you can always do)

```
member.addRole(member.guild.roles.find("name","Guild").id);
```

Even afterwards, you need the ID as the add role function can only accepct [Snowflakes](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/Snowflake).

```
//The only reason I use var is because I can redefine it later
role = role.id;
```

Then, call the add role function.

```
member.addRole(role);
```

Done!

**If you see an error about a DepreciationWarning, that can be ignored, but its recommended to also use this line of code as to define role:**

```
var role = member.guild.roles.get(r=>["Guest"].includes(r.name));
role = role.id
//continue with code, but define role in member.AddRole
```

[For more info, click here](https://discord.js.org)

Edit 2:

The bot is missing perms. Make sure the bot is on top / over the guest role.